# Twitter follow button - need to track universal google analytics

Tags: twitter, google-analytics

I am having a twitter tweet button, I am using knockout js, how can I track the number of events using universal google analytics?

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-bind="attr: { 'data-text': vote}" data-count="none">Tweet</a>
```

I have the below script in my knockout js which is not working

```
$('.is-voting-complete').on('click', '.twitter-share-button', function () {
    gaTracker.send('event', 'Social', 'Twitter', 'Tweet');
});
```

I am guessing there is a iframe which twitter is incorporating , because of which the on click is not firing.
can somebody please help me with this

Comment: Haven't tested, but this site describes a way as long as you use the button as provided by twitter: http://technicalmarketing.io/analytics/cool-google-analytics-hacks-using-the-new-universal-analytics-js/

Comment: it is not working, it is saying twttr is not defined.

Comment: MisterPhilip,i did not understand the edit you suggested can you pelase let me know exactly what I need to change in order to make my code work

Answer (score 2):

twittr is not defined because you have not included Twitters's widget.js. You should include the following before the closing body tag.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
```

you can create a button like this

```
<a class="tw" target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet? text=Check%20this%20out&amp;related=episod&amp;url=TheUrl"></a>
```

then bind google analytics function to the tweet event

```
twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
 twttr.events.bind('tweet', function(e){
  if(!e) return;
  ga('send', 'social', 'twitter', 'tweet', theURL);
 }
});
```

I have created a plugin called [gasotracker](https://github.com/rolandkal/gasotracker). It works with twitter, but you are able to track other social events on your site.